# Binding a control to a nested property

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, data-binding

Basic question, which I've exhaustively searched for a full day.

My Account object has a KeyType object, which has a Name property, all generated by Linq to SQL.

My BindingSource:

```
var result = from account in Schema.Accounts select account as Account;
Data = new ComplexBindingList<Account>(result.ToList<Account>());
DataSource = Data;
ResetBindings(true);
```

My ComplexBindingList borrowed from a blog by Bradley Smith has this interface:

```
public class ComplexBindingList<T> : List<T>, ITypedList
```

This works on my DataGridView:

```
Columns.Add(CreateColumn("KeyType.Name", "Key Type");
```

The data's fine, as this code works just before the exception:

```
var v = account.KeyType.Name;
```

This doesn't work on my TextBox. I get an exception "Property accessor 'Name' on object 'EPM.BODA.KeyType' threw the following exception:'Object does not match target type.'"

```
// Controller is my BindingSource
Binding binding = EditField.DataBindings.Add("Text", Controller, "KeyType.Name");
```

I have a general impression that reflection isn't working properly but can't seem to find the details on how to fill in the gap. Cheers for any help.

Comment: where have you initialized account? dont you mean result.KeyType.Name?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far, as a simple workaround.

```
public virtual Binding GetBinding(string fieldName)
{
    string[] pieces = fieldName.Split('.');
    if ( pieces.GetLength(0) == 1 )
    {
        return new Binding("Text", this, fieldName);
    }
    else
    {
        return new Binding("Text",
            Current.GetType().GetProperty(pieces[0]).GetValue(Current, null), pieces[1]);
    }
}

// Calling the helper function and adding the binding
EditField.DataBindings.Add(Controller.GetBinding(mapping.FieldName));
```